# Parent component not receiving child event in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a problem where an event is fired but the parent can't seem to listen to it. I have burned more than 3 hours trying to locate the problem to no avail.
Here is the parent component.

**Thread.vue**

```js
    <script>
    import Tagging from '../components/Tagging.vue';

    export default {
        props: ['thread'],

        components: {Tagging},

        data () {
            return {
                repliesCount: this.thread.replies_count,
                locked: this.thread.locked,
                title: this.thread.title,
                body: this.thread.body,
                selectedTags: this.thread.selected_tags,
                form: {},
                editing: false
            };
        },
        methods: {
            tagsChanged(value){ <---- this handler is never called
                console.log("received")
            }
        }

    }
</script>
```

And the child component

**Tagging.vue**

```html
    <!-- Vue component -->
    <template>
     <div>
    <label class="typo__label">Tagging:</label>
    <multiselect
      v-model="value"
      tag-placeholder="Add this as new tag"
      placeholder="Search or add a tag"
      label="name"
      track-by="code"
      :options="options"
      :multiple="true"
      :taggable="true"
      @tag="addTag"
      @input="emitToParent" //this event handler emits an event to parent
    ></multiselect>
    </div>
   </template>

   <script>
     import Multiselect from "vue-multiselect";

export default {
  props: ["tags","previousTags","repliesCount"],
  components: {
    Multiselect
  },
  data() {
    return {
      value: this.previousTags,
      options: this.tags,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addTag(newTag) {
      const tag = {
        name: newTag,
        code: newTag.substring(0, 2) + Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000000)
      };
      this.options.push(tag);
      this.previousTags.push(tag);
      this.form.selected_tags.push(tag)
    },
    emitToParent (event) {
      this.$emit('childToParent', this.value)//this event is being fired(verified on vue developer tools
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

And on my HTML here is the template

```html
<tagging @childToParent="tagsChanged" :tags="some json" :previous-tags="some json"></tagging>
```

I have tried changing

`@childToParent="tagsChanged"`

to

`v-on:childToParent="tagsChanged"`

But it doesn't work.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: Please share your template in `Thread.vue` component on how are you using your child component.

Answer (score 0):

On the surface the `$emit` part looks ok.

First, can you add a `console.log()` to `emitToParent` to make sure you are firing this method.

Second, make sure you are not getting any errors, check the console.

Thirdly, this is incorrect syntax: `:tags="some json" :previous-tags="some json"`. This would throw an error.

Comment: There are no errors on the console, the handler method will just not be called. emitToParent logs a message, and the event is also visible on Vue build tools. 
This: ``` :tags="some json" :previous-tags="some json" ``` I just stripped some code for brevity.